# Sql server XML path with two columns from two table

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I have below Query

```
SELECT F.ID,
                 (S.Parameter + '="' + F.Value + '"') AS params
                 FROM FirstTable F WITH (NOLOCK)
            LEFT JOIN SecondTable S ON
                F.ID = S.ID
```

Output is like below

```
ID  params
21  rev="REVENUE"
21  cv_1="CUSTOM1"
21  cv_2="CUSTOM2"
20  rev="Revvv"
20  cv_1="cus 1"
20  cv_2="cus2 "
```

I want output like

```
ID  params
21  rev="REVENUE";cv_1="CUSTOM1";cv_2="CUSTOM2"
20  rev="Revvv";cv_1="cus 1";cv_2="cus2"
```

I tried using Stuff and XML Path but unable to get the desired output,

I am trying

```
SELECT      F.ID,
                 STUFF( (SELECT (';' + S.Parameter + '="' + F.Value + '"') AS params
              FROM FirstTable F WITH (NOLOCK)
            LEFT JOIN SecondTable S ON
                S.ID = F.MacroID
               WHERE F.ID = S.ID
               FOR XML PATH ('')
              ), 1, 1, '') as params
            FROM FirstTable F WITH (NOLOCK)
            LEFT JOIN SecondTable S ON
                S.ID = F.ID
```

Could someone plz help me with this..

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, you want:

```
SELECT F.ID,
       STUFF( (SELECT (';' + S.Parameter + '="' + S.Value + '"') 
               FROM SecondTable S
               WHERE F.ID = S.DID
               FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
              ).VALUE('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
                     ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as params
FROM FirstTable F ;
```

Comment: Sorry there was slightly mistake in query, the S.Value is actually from F table

Answer (score 0):

You can add `STRING_AGG` with `group by` to your existing code (`STRING_AGG` is supported in `SQL Server 2017+`)

```
Select ID, string_agg(params, ';')
from (
SELECT F.ID,
        (S.Parameter + '="' + F.Value + '"') AS params
        FROM FirstTable F WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN SecondTable S ON
        F.ID = S.DID
) a
group by ID
```

Comment: I am using 2012